# Define command that returns true/false (multiple conditions)

Tags: conditionals

While using the `datatool`-package I encountered something strange. I have a loop, and each iteration it defines some variables that are later used by the command `\DTLforeach` from the `datatool`-package. The command has an optional argument, those are conditions which are different for each iteration and thus need to be declared using a command (instead of copying the table 14 times).

I'll use the package `ifthen` instead of the `datatool`-package because it's more commonly used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\def\One{abc}
\def\Two{cde}

\def\condition{\equal{\One}{\One} \AND \equal{\Two}{\Two}}

\begin{document}

\ifthenelse{\condition}{% if condition returns true
  True.
}{% if condition returns false
  False.
}

\end{document}
```

This results in an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence
<argument> \AND

l.11 \ifthenelse{\condition}
                            {% if condition returns true
```

However, it works if you copy-paste the contents of `\condition` into the first argument of `\ifthenelse`. Replacing `\AND` with its lowercase version `\and` doesn't work either. The error message just gets more complex, but it's still an undefined control sequence.

A possible solution is to define 2 separate conditions. This is however not a preferred way of doing it because the number of conditions is not always limited to 2, I'll not always use `\AND`, I'd have to iterate through them inside the `\ifthenelse` (which I don't know if possible), and so on. Also, it would make the code less clear, so if there is a possible way of defining several conditions in one variable that would be great.

(I also tried the `\setboolean`, but it only accepts the strings `true` or `false` and no real conditions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an expansion issue. You should expand `\condition` before pass it to `\ifthenelse`. Use

```
\expandafter\ifthenelse\expandafter{\condition}{% if condition returns true
  True.
}{% if condition returns false
  False.
}
```

you will get correct result.

Comment: Thought it had to be something like that. Problem is I don't understand the command `\expandafter` exactly, and certainly not with commands. Mind telling me how to organize the `\expandafter`s if I use `\csname` to define the condition? I hope this works the same for the `datatool`-command. Thanks already for the answer!

Comment: Ok, with some guesswork I managed to find it, but seriously 6? `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifthenelse\expandafter\expandafter\expandafer{\condition}...`. Thanks again `:)`

Comment: Yes, seriously, six! Appendix D of the TeXbook (titled 'Dirty Tricks') illustrates how to expand `\a\b\c\d` in reverse order, and it takes 11 `\expandafter` calls. Knuth remarks that this is "probably too lengthy to be of any use" (Appendix D should come with a straitjacket in a handy pocket at the end of the chapter).

Comment: Probably a good thing they are working on a new version then `:)`

Comment: @Didii: That's why `etoolbox` and `expl3` are useful.